# HDFS Plugin for Apache Ranger

Tags: apache, authorization, hdfs, acl

I am planning to use Apache Ranger for authorization of my HDFS file system. I have a question on the capability of apache ranger plugin. Does HDFS plugin for Apache ranger offers more security features than just managing HDFS ACLs ? From the limited understanding that i gathered by looking into the presentations/blogs, I am unable to comprehend the functions of HDFS plugin for Apache Ranger.

Answer (score 1):

..and now with the latest version of ApacheRanger it is possible to define "deny" rules.
Previously it was just possible to define rules which specifies additional "allow" privileges, on top of the underlying HDFS ACLs. Hence , if you had HDFS ACL for a directory set to "777", everybody can access it, independant from any Ranger-HDFS-policy on top of that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ranger plugin for HDFS will provide user access auditing with below fields:

IP, Resource type, Timestamp, Access granted/denied.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Ranger plugin does not actually *use* HDFS ACLs. Ranger policies are added on top of standard HDFS permissions and HDFS ACLs.

You need to be aware that any access rights that are granted on these lower levels cannot be taken away by Ranger anymore.

Apart from that, Ranger gives you the same possibilities as ACLs, plus some more, like granting access by client IP range.